# print rest of line after n consecutive character appears

Tags: awk, sed

I want to print the rest of a string line after the n-th consecutive appearance of a character(`;`).

For example:

```
string -> USER=5000;ALL;tree1;tree1;4;;3;MM_;;;;;;;;main
```

I want to print the rest of the line after the 5-th appearance of `;` using `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Delete up to the fifth or nth ; and print the rest

```
$ awk '{sub(/^([^;]*;){5}/,"")}1' file
;3;MM_;;;;;;;;main
```

Comment: It's not working.It's printing the full line:                                                               awk '{sub(/^([^;]*;){5}/,"")}1' sed_test.txt
USER=5000;ALL;tree1;tree1;4;;3;MM_;;;;;;;;main

Comment: That's interesting, works just fine here. Which awk do you have?

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** approach(accepts optional parameter `n` to specify the number of  `;` occurrences):

```
s="string -> USER=5000;ALL;tree1;tree1;4;;3;MM_;;;;;;;;main"
echo $s | awk -F';' -v n=5 '{o=""; for(i=n+1;i<=NF;i++){ o=o $i FS }{print o}}' OFS=';'
```

---

***sed*** approach:

```
s="string -> USER=5000;ALL;tree1;tree1;4;;3;MM_;;;;;;;;main"
echo $s | sed -En 's/^([^;]*;){5}//p'
```

The output(for both approaches):

```
;3;MM_;;;;;;;;main
```

---

`-E` option, allows extended regular expressions

Comment: Which parameter I should modify in the command if I want all the line UNTIL the 5 th appearance of ; ?

Comment: @vivid, just change loop definition to this `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)` to get all until ...

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'4;' '{print $2}' file

;3;MM_;;;;;;;;main
```